# #sql-ib***.ibd files fills up the disk after a couple of hours

Tags: mysql, replication

Why are these files created? They fills up the disk on my slave server (master/slave replication)

```
#sql-ib219492-948768181.ibd
```

The slave is created via Percona xtrabackup from a master backup

```
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir="$mysql_restore_dir"
xtrabackup --move-back --target-dir="$mysql_restore_dir"
rm -r $mysql_restore_dir/*
chown -R mysql.mysql $mysql_dir

mysql -u root -p$slave_pass -e "RESET MASTER;\
    SET GLOBAL gtid_purged='$gtid';\
    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='$master_host', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='$master_pass', MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1;\
    START SLAVE"
```

## my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                       = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
symbolic_links                 = 0

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 2
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
log_slave_updates
expire_logs_days               = 1
sync_binlog                    = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators= 1
binlog_format                  = ROW
slave_sql_verify_checksum      = 1

# REPLICATION #
gtid_mode                      = 1
enforce_gtid_consistency
replicate_do_db                = mydb
#super_read_only                = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group           = 2
innodb_log_file_size                = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size              = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 2
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 1

basedir                        = /usr
tmpdir                         = /tmp
lc_messages_dir                = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` returns

[image]

## SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES

```
Variable_name
Value
auto_generate_certs
ON
auto_increment_increment
1
auto_increment_offset
1
autocommit
ON
automatic_sp_privileges
ON
avoid_temporal_upgrade
OFF
back_log
150
basedir
/usr/
big_tables
OFF
bind_address
*
binlog_cache_size
32768
binlog_checksum
CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates
OFF
binlog_error_action
ABORT_SERVER
binlog_format
ROW
binlog_group_commit_sync_delay
0
binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count
0
binlog_gtid_simple_recovery
ON
binlog_max_flush_queue_time
0
binlog_order_commits
ON
binlog_row_image
FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events
OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size
32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size
25000
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking
COMMIT_ORDER
block_encryption_mode
aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size
8388608
character_set_client
latin1
character_set_connection
latin1
character_set_database
latin1
character_set_filesystem
binary
character_set_results
latin1
character_set_server
latin1
character_set_system
utf8
character_sets_dir
/usr/share/mysql/charsets/
check_proxy_users
OFF
collation_connection
latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database
latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server
latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type
NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert
AUTO
connect_timeout
10
core_file
OFF
datadir
/var/lib/mysql/
date_format
%Y-%m-%d
datetime_format
%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_authentication_plugin
mysql_native_password
default_password_lifetime
0
default_storage_engine
InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine
InnoDB
default_week_format
0
delay_key_write
ON
delayed_insert_limit
100
delayed_insert_timeout
300
delayed_queue_size
1000
disabled_storage_engines
disconnect_on_expired_password
ON
div_precision_increment
4
end_markers_in_json
OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency
ON
eq_range_index_dive_limit
200
event_scheduler
OFF
expire_logs_days
1
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
ON
flush
OFF
flush_time
0
foreign_key_checks
ON
ft_boolean_syntax
+ -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len
84
ft_min_word_len
4
ft_query_expansion_limit
20
ft_stopword_file
(built-in)
general_log
OFF
general_log_file
/var/lib/mysql/rep-dynaccount.log
group_concat_max_len
1024
gtid_executed
3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
fe51e8df-b7c4-11e9-be21-4061862b8d34:1-25706017
gtid_executed_compression_period
1000
gtid_mode
ON
gtid_owned
gtid_purged
3ccc2392-45ed-11e7-bc98-4061862b8d34:1-35942477,
fe51e8df-b7c4-11e9-be21-4061862b8d34:1-25706017
have_compress
YES
have_crypt
YES
have_dynamic_loading
YES
have_geometry
YES
have_openssl
YES
have_profiling
YES
have_query_cache
YES
have_rtree_keys
YES
have_ssl
YES
have_statement_timeout
YES
have_symlink
DISABLED
host_cache_size
628
hostname
rep-dynaccount
ignore_builtin_innodb
OFF
ignore_db_dirs
init_connect
init_file
init_slave
innodb_adaptive_flushing
ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm
10
Variable_name
Value
 
innodb_adaptive_hash_index
ON
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts
8
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay
150000
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval
5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock
OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog
OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl
OFF
innodb_api_trx_level
0
innodb_autoextend_increment
64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode
2
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size
134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown
ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct
25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename
ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances
1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup
ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now
OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size
1073741824
innodb_change_buffer_max_size
25
innodb_change_buffering
all
innodb_checksum_algorithm
crc32
innodb_checksums
ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled
OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency
0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct
5
innodb_compression_level
6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max
50
innodb_concurrency_tickets
5000
innodb_data_file_path
ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir
innodb_deadlock_detect
ON
innodb_default_row_format
dynamic
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache
OFF
innodb_doublewrite
ON
innodb_fast_shutdown
1
innodb_file_format
Barracuda
innodb_file_format_check
ON
innodb_file_format_max
Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table
ON
innodb_fill_factor
100
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout
1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit
2
innodb_flush_method
O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors
1
innodb_flush_sync
ON
innodb_flushing_avg_loops
30
innodb_force_load_corrupted
OFF
innodb_force_recovery
0
innodb_ft_aux_table
innodb_ft_cache_size
8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print
OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword
ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size
84
innodb_ft_min_token_size
3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize
2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit
2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree
2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size
640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
innodb_io_capacity
200
innodb_io_capacity_max
2000
innodb_large_prefix
ON
innodb_lock_wait_timeout
50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog
OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size
67108864
innodb_log_checksums
ON
innodb_log_compressed_pages
ON
innodb_log_file_size
536870912
innodb_log_files_in_group
2
innodb_log_group_home_dir
./
innodb_log_write_ahead_size
8192
innodb_lru_scan_depth
1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct
75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm
0.000000
innodb_max_purge_lag
0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay
0
innodb_max_undo_log_size
1073741824
innodb_monitor_disable
innodb_monitor_enable
innodb_monitor_reset
innodb_monitor_reset_all
innodb_numa_interleave
OFF
innodb_old_blocks_pct
37
innodb_old_blocks_time
1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size
134217728
innodb_open_files
2245
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only
OFF
innodb_page_cleaners
1
innodb_page_size
16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks
OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size
300
innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency
128
innodb_purge_threads
4
innodb_random_read_ahead
OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold
56
innodb_read_io_threads
4
innodb_read_only
OFF
Variable_name
Value
 
innodb_replication_delay
0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout
OFF
innodb_rollback_segments
128
innodb_sort_buffer_size
1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay
6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc
ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked
OFF
innodb_stats_method
nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata
OFF
innodb_stats_persistent
ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages
20
innodb_stats_sample_pages
8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages
8
innodb_status_output
OFF
innodb_status_output_locks
OFF
innodb_strict_mode
ON
innodb_support_xa
ON
innodb_sync_array_size
1
innodb_sync_spin_loops
30
innodb_table_locks
ON
innodb_temp_data_file_path
ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb_thread_concurrency
0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay
10000
innodb_tmpdir
innodb_undo_directory
./
innodb_undo_log_truncate
OFF
innodb_undo_logs
128
innodb_undo_tablespaces
0
innodb_use_native_aio
ON
innodb_version
5.7.33
innodb_write_io_threads
4
interactive_timeout
28800
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine
InnoDB
join_buffer_size
262144
keep_files_on_create
OFF
key_buffer_size
8388608
key_cache_age_threshold
300
key_cache_block_size
1024
key_cache_division_limit
100
keyring_operations
ON
large_files_support
ON
large_page_size
0
large_pages
OFF
lc_messages
en_US
lc_messages_dir
/usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names
en_US
license
GPL
local_infile
ON
lock_wait_timeout
31536000
locked_in_memory
OFF
log_bin
ON
log_bin_basename
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
log_bin_index
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators
ON
log_bin_use_v1_row_events
OFF
log_builtin_as_identified_by_password
OFF
log_error
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_error_verbosity
3
log_output
FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes
ON
log_slave_updates
OFF
log_slow_admin_statements
OFF
log_slow_slave_statements
OFF
log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog
ON
log_syslog
OFF
log_syslog_facility
daemon
log_syslog_include_pid
ON
log_syslog_tag
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes
0
log_timestamps
UTC
log_warnings
2
long_query_time
1.000000
low_priority_updates
OFF
lower_case_file_system
OFF
lower_case_table_names
0
master_info_repository
FILE
master_verify_checksum
OFF
max_allowed_packet
16777216
max_binlog_cache_size
18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size
1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size
18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors
1000000
max_connections
500
max_delayed_threads
20
max_digest_length
1024
max_error_count
64
max_execution_time
0
max_heap_table_size
67108864
max_insert_delayed_threads
20
max_join_size
18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data
1024
max_points_in_geometry
65536
max_prepared_stmt_count
16382
max_relay_log_size
0
max_seeks_for_key
18446744073709551615
max_sort_length
1024
max_sp_recursion_depth
0
max_tmp_tables
32
max_user_connections
0
max_write_lock_count
18446744073709551615
Variable_name
Value
 
metadata_locks_cache_size
1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances
8
min_examined_row_limit
0
multi_range_count
256
myisam_data_pointer_size
6
myisam_max_sort_file_size
9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size
18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options
OFF
myisam_repair_threads
1
myisam_sort_buffer_size
8388608
myisam_stats_method
nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap
OFF
mysql_native_password_proxy_users
OFF
net_buffer_length
16384
net_read_timeout
30
net_retry_count
10
net_write_timeout
60
new
OFF
ngram_token_size
2
offline_mode
OFF
old
OFF
old_alter_table
OFF
old_passwords
0
open_files_limit
5000
optimizer_prune_level
1
optimizer_search_depth
62
optimizer_switch
index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,prefer_ordering_index=on
optimizer_trace
enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features
greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit
1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size
16384
optimizer_trace_offset
-1
parser_max_mem_size
18446744073709551615
performance_schema
ON
performance_schema_accounts_size
-1
performance_schema_digests_size
10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size
10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size
10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size
10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size
10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size
10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size
10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size
10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size
10
performance_schema_hosts_size
-1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes
80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_digest_length
1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes
80
performance_schema_max_file_handles
32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_index_stat
-1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes
320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks
-1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes
210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_program_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes
50
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes
10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length
1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes
150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes
193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack
10
performance_schema_max_table_handles
-1
performance_schema_max_table_instances
-1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat
-1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes
50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances
-1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size
512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size
-1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size
-1
performance_schema_users_size
-1
pid_file
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
port
3306
preload_buffer_size
32768
profiling
OFF
profiling_history_size
15
protocol_version
10
query_alloc_block_size
8192
query_cache_limit
1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit
4096
query_cache_size
0
query_cache_type
OFF
query_cache_wlock_invalidate
OFF
query_prealloc_size
8192
range_alloc_block_size
4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size
8388608
rbr_exec_mode
STRICT
read_buffer_size
131072
read_only
OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size
262144
relay_log
relay_log_basename
/var/lib/mysql/rep-dynaccount-relay-bin
relay_log_index
/var/lib/mysql/rep-dynaccount-relay-bin.index
relay_log_info_file
relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository
FILE
Variable_name
Value
 
relay_log_purge
ON
relay_log_recovery
OFF
relay_log_space_limit
0
replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config
OFF
replication_sender_observe_commit_only
OFF
report_host
report_password
report_port
3306
report_user
require_secure_transport
OFF
rpl_stop_slave_timeout
31536000
secure_auth
ON
secure_file_priv
/var/lib/mysql-files/
server_id
2
server_id_bits
32
server_uuid
a9aa0e50-7240-11eb-8681-96000080ccbb
session_track_gtids
OFF
session_track_schema
ON
session_track_state_change
OFF
session_track_system_variables
time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection
session_track_transaction_info
OFF
sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys
ON
sha256_password_private_key_path
private_key.pem
sha256_password_proxy_users
OFF
sha256_password_public_key_path
public_key.pem
show_compatibility_56
OFF
show_create_table_verbosity
OFF
show_old_temporals
OFF
skip_external_locking
ON
skip_name_resolve
ON
skip_networking
OFF
skip_show_database
OFF
slave_allow_batching
OFF
slave_checkpoint_group
512
slave_checkpoint_period
300
slave_compressed_protocol
OFF
slave_exec_mode
STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir
/tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet
1073741824
slave_net_timeout
60
slave_parallel_type
DATABASE
slave_parallel_workers
0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max
16777216
slave_preserve_commit_order
OFF
slave_rows_search_algorithms
TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors
OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum
ON
slave_transaction_retries
10
slave_type_conversions
slow_launch_time
2
slow_query_log
ON
slow_query_log_file
/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
socket
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort_buffer_size
262144
sql_auto_is_null
OFF
sql_big_selects
ON
sql_buffer_result
OFF
sql_log_off
OFF
sql_mode
STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes
ON
sql_quote_show_create
ON
sql_safe_updates
OFF
sql_select_limit
18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter
0
sql_warnings
OFF
ssl_ca
ca.pem
ssl_capath
ssl_cert
server-cert.pem
ssl_cipher
ssl_crl
ssl_crlpath
ssl_key
server-key.pem
stored_program_cache
256
super_read_only
OFF
sync_binlog
1
sync_frm
ON
sync_master_info
10000
sync_relay_log
10000
sync_relay_log_info
10000
system_time_zone
CET
table_definition_cache
4096
table_open_cache
2245
table_open_cache_instances
16
thread_cache_size
50
thread_handling
one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack
262144
time_format
%H:%i:%s
time_zone
SYSTEM
tls_version
TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
tmp_table_size
67108864
tmpdir
/tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size
8192
transaction_isolation
REPEATABLE-READ
transaction_prealloc_size
4096
transaction_read_only
OFF
transaction_write_set_extraction
OFF
tx_isolation
REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only
OFF
unique_checks
ON
updatable_views_with_limit
YES
Variable_name
Value
```

Comment: That looks like a temporary table. Could you provide the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?

Comment: @jynus have updated the question with the results of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Comment: on which directory this file is created ? Can you post output of ```SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES ``` ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI question updated with the output

Comment: @clarkk Is tmp_dir same on Master & slave server ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ??? Please run `SELECT VERSION();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem does not seem that easy to solve, but perhaps I can point you in the right direction.

Did you know that MySQL can create temp tables on its own for its internal use ??? The MySQL Docs have a Page called "Internal Temporary Table Use in MySQL" in [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html), [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html), and [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html). Since MySQL 5.7, internal temp tables use InnoDB (See [internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine))

The first line on each page says

> In some cases, the server creates internal temporary tables while processing statements. Users have no direct control over when this occurs.

Looking the MySQL 8.0 Docs, here are possible scenarios for Internal Temp Tables:

> The server creates temporary tables under conditions such as these:
>
> - Evaluation of UNION statements, with some exceptions described later.
> - Evaluation of some views, such those that use the TEMPTABLE algorithm, UNION, or aggregation.
> - Evaluation of derived tables (see Section 13.2.11.8, “Derived Tables”).
> - Evaluation of common table expressions (see Section 13.2.15, “WITH (Common Table Expressions)”).
> - Tables created for subquery or semijoin materialization (see Section 8.2.2, “Optimizing Subqueries, Derived Tables, View References, and Common Table Expressions”).
> - Evaluation of statements that contain an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or for which the ORDER BY or GROUP BY
>   contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join
>   queue.
> - Evaluation of DISTINCT combined with ORDER BY may require a temporary table.
> - For queries that use the SQL_SMALL_RESULT modifier, MySQL uses an in-memory temporary table, unless the query also contains elements
>   (described later) that require on-disk storage.
> - To evaluate INSERT ... SELECT statements that select from and insert into the same table, MySQL creates an internal temporary table to hold
>   the rows from the SELECT, then inserts those rows into the target
>   table. See Section 13.2.6.1, “INSERT ... SELECT Statement”.
> - Evaluation of multiple-table UPDATE statements.
> - Evaluation of GROUP_CONCAT() or COUNT(DISTINCT) expressions.
> - Evaluation of window functions (see Section 12.21, “Window Functions”) uses temporary tables as necessary.

So, if the Master executes `INSERT ... SELECT` with lots or rows, that could be one possibility. This would definite manifest itself if Seconds_Behind_Master climbs steadily or very suddenly (like 0 to 600 if `INSERT ... SELECT` took 10 min to run on the Master). This is just an educated guess ([like Mr. Spock did in the movie "STAR TREK : The Voyage Home"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBxcalnSzIk)).

Please look over all the bulletpoints and see if any of them apply.

You can then plan around this behavior by changing the [slave_load_tmpdir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-replica.html#sysvar_slave_load_tmpdir) or [tmpdir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir) on the Slave to be on a different disk (SSD or HDD).

I hope this post helps you.

### UPDATE 2021-02-27 18:04 EST

I just noticed [your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/285663/sql-ib-ibd-files-fills-up-the-disk-after-a-couple-of-hours/286055?noredirect=1#comment560204_286055):

> Have found out that the #sql* files on the slave are created at the same time when OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl is executed on the master on all tables in the database

If you do not want [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) to replicate from the Master, there are two things you can do.

#### SUGGESTION #1 : [Use `NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG` or `LOCAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html)

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG tbname;
```

or

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE LOCAL tbname;
```

#### SUGGESTION #2 : Disable Session Level binlogging

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
OPTIMIZE TABLE tbname;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

### UPDATE 2021-02-28 12:56 EST

[There is a bug report from MySQL 5.1.56 which appears to be unresolved](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62474) with the title `Optimize table dropping big tables`. Perhaps the table being optimized has a foreign key (just speculation). Also, please check that the table being optimized has not disappeared from the slave.

### UPDATE 2021-02-28 13:10 EST

Here is an additional workaround

Execute this on the Slave as well as on the Master

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG tbname;
```

The temp table should no longer appear.

You should setup another Master/Slave cluster with the Latest version of MySQL and see if `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the Slave still eaves behind a large temp table.

Comment: Ok, but why does mysql not delete these files when they are not in use anymore? I can delete them without the slave replication fails

Comment: Have found out that the `#sql*` files on the `slave` are created at the same time when `OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl` is executed on the `master` on all tables in the database

Comment: @clarkk Posted suggestions for you ...

Comment: but I don't understand why the files aren't deleted when they are not in use anymore. I delete them from time to time and the replication is still running

Comment: I have two Questions : Can you see OPTIMIZE TABLE in the SQL thread the processlist ??? Have you every shutdown mysqld on the Slave while it was in the middle of executing `OPTIMIZE TABLE`; ???

Comment: The slave is never stopped or anything. The optimize is done in the night so have never checked the processlist.. just checked the modified date of the files yesterday and checked the time for the maintenance cronjob

Comment: If you manually execute `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the Master, does the temp table drop down  in size on the Slave ???

Comment: no, new files are created